# Python 3.x installed, but python UNIX commands starts Python 2.x

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos

I downloaded python 3.3.0 which is latest version and i finished installing 
now I want to run it in my centOS linux but when i type it in console "python" , python 2.7.0 which is bundled with os installation runs.
how can i change it to run 3?
I vaguely feel that i have to change the code about path in bin folder or something

Comment: Did you install it through yum, or did you do it manually?

Comment: try exec: ls -la /usr/bin | grep python
There are symlinks e.g. python -> python2.7
So I guess you could just change this link to python -> python3.3

Comment: @rzymek: that's no go, see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If running `python` from your command line, the search order for an executable named `python` is determined by your `$PATH` environment variable.  `echo $PATH` will show you your path search order; earlier directories have precedence over latter ones.

If you type `which python` you'll see what your machine determined to be the first `python` in your search path.

Most likely, however, is the case where you have a symlink inside `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin` named `python` which points to the python binary.

In most systems, there are actually two symlinks,

```
python  -> pythonX
pythonX -> pythonX.Y
```

For example,

```
python  -> python2
python2 -> python2.7
```

You can see whether your `python` is actually just a symlink with something like

```
ls -l $(which python)
```

In my case, this gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin/python -> python2
```

Showing that python is a symlink to python2

I could go further by typing

```
ls -l $(which python2)
```

In my case, this gives me

```
/usr/local/bin/python2 -> python2.7
```

---

So anyway, you have a few choices

1)  Add a symlink from `python` to the python version you want (probably `python3`) in some directory higher on the `$PATH` food-chain -- in a directory earlier in the list.  For example, `/usr/local/bin` is usually higher than `/usr/bin`.

2) Change your current `python` symlink to point to the python version you want.  Usually this is done by adding the force `-f` flag to `ln`.

3) Explicitly stating that you want to run python 3.x by typing `python3` on the command line or using `#!/bin/env python3` as the hash-bang in your scripts.

4) Alias `python` to `python3` in your .bashrc or equivalent file (eg `alias python='/path/to/python3`).

The first two options may have wider reaching impact than you expect.  For example, they will break the `yum` package manager, since it only specifies `python`.

The third might get a bit tedious, but it's more precise, and will allow everything to, by default, use python2 except the scripts you specifically call python3.

The last is a decent compromise, allowing you the ease of just typing `python` but not affecting other users.

It's all up to you really.

Comment: thanks a lot , you added up my knowledge about linux

Answer (score 6):

Try commands:

```
python3.3
```

Or

```
python3
```

Python commands and compatibility http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

**You should not change system defaults by symlinking Python 3 to Python 2**, because this potentially breaks your operating system which relies to the fact that system default `python` is Python 2.x (referred by start up scripts, applications, etc.)

If you want to run Python 3 when you type command `python` add the following to your shell configuratin file:

```
 alias python=python3
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to know how to run the `python3` interpreter *just typing* `python` or having `# /bin/python` on his sources. Your answer isn't quite answering that.

Comment: Clarified that it is no no